# How to make zapier add 1 field per row when importing to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I want to make the jira -> Google Sheets zap create 1 row per issue, with each field in its own column.  Is there a special delimiter to include b/t fields in the Rows portion of the "Edit Template" step?

[image]

The above just concatenate the 2 fields into 1 value for the cell A1

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It looks like your spreadsheet hasn't been set up to work with Zapier. Namely, you have to pre-declare all columns:

[image]

There are [instructions here](https://zapier.com/help/how-setup-your-google-spreadsheet-work-zapier/) about setting it up.

Comment: BTW I notice you start nearly all your answers with the same message - it's not directly relevant to the answer that you work for the Zapier platform team - you've told us in your profile, so it's unnecessary. See, e.g. [Should editors excise signatures in answers even if they contain useful organisation information?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363528/1364007) for a discussion on the issue.